# My arcs are backwards, what is wrong?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, arc-length

CNC engraving machines use a language called GCode to describe movements of the x,y plane.
Here is a small example :

```
G01 X7.2 Y-0.3 (the position of the start of the arc)
G03 X6.8 Y-0.2 I-0.4 J-3.3 (the end of the arc and it's relative centre point)
```

This says go to 7.2, -0.3 and draw an anticlockwise arc TO 6.8, -0.2
the arc is centred at (6.8 - 0.4), (-0.2 - (-3.3))

I'm trying to replace the arc (G03 command) with a series of interpolated simple points (G01) commands.

To do this I begin by calculating the :

radius $\sqrt( i^2 + j^2 )$

chord $\sqrt(( x - previous X)^2 + (y - previous Y) ^2 )$

Theta (angle of whole arc) $arcos( 1 - (chord ^ 2) / (2 * (radius ^ 2) )$

The angle at the start of the arc $atan2(previous Y - arc Centre X, previous X - arc Centre Y)$

*One suspects the atan2 may be part of the problem as something is PI radians out of place?*

Now I can divide up theta into a number of sub angles, then starting from the start angle I can add that sub angle, and recalculate a new point on the arc as follows :

```
for n times:
  co = radius * cos(startangle - some nth of theta)
  si = radius * sin(startangle - some nth of theta)
  x of new point on arc is (arc centre x + co)
  y of new point on arc is (arc centre y + si)
```

But I get this!

[image]

You can see that the arc is calculated correctly but is 180 degrees wrong.
That is, it is convex, where it should be concave!

Can anyone just point me at roughly where I've made a mistake?
I would show my whole code but my question wouldn't be cogent.
I've been at this for 6 hours and I haven't managed to change anything that has fixed this.
Perhaps a mathematician will just look at this and know what the issue is?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I am not sure this forum is appropriate for your question. Is there a CNC StackExchange or forum you could cross-post this question to? A priori, it does not seem to me that people studying math would be any better equipped to figure out where your bug is compared to anyone else with some technical competence.

Comment: Think of it as a question about bearings, or polar vs cartesian coodinates rather than a question about robots.

Comment: This is not truly a math question but a programming one

Comment: True, but the stack overflow would say I've got the maths wrong. Its worth a shot, I just thought a bored mathematician might like look at the problem.

Comment: Haven't tried to understand the code in detail (and I don't speak GCode), but in case it matters, in the `atan2` expression the coordinates of the arc center appear to be swapped...? That is, you have `atan2(previousY−arcCentre**X**,previousX−arcCentre**Y**)`.